# Xamarin.Forms class in namespace not found (only on iOS)

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've a Xamarin.Forms solutions, which consists of several PCLs and device-specific projects:

- MyApp.Controls (Portable)

  - Helper (MyApp.Controls.Helper)
- MyApp.App (Portable)
- MyApp.iOS
- MyApp.Android

MyApp.App is my main implementation, where the App.xaml and all Views/ ViewModels are implemented. This project references MyApp.Controls and refers to this project within XAML via xmlns. The XAML-references work fine on Android but on iOS I get the following exception:
controls:MyClass not found in xmlns clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls.Helper;assembly=MyApp.Controls

I have no idea, why "MyClass" can't be resolved on iOS. I'm using Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.180.

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding the whole solution?

Comment: Try adding a reference to the MyApp.Controls assembly to your iOS project directly.

Comment: Thanks. I had added the references, but the solution was to call a method from that assembly so that it was loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely because there is no C# code being used for the assembly so the compiler is not including it. You can confirm this by adding a quick stub of code in your AppDelegate. For example,

```
new MyClass();
```

Just add a line like that in the FinishedLaunching method so the compiler knows you are using code from the reference assembly and will include. If that does appear to be the issue, you can do something slightly prettier like include an `Init` method in that library.